# How do you change the title bar color in Visual Studio 2019 C++ WinForms?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface, visual-studio-2019

Hello I am a beginner at WinForms for C++ but in C++ i have gotten up to the point of where I am learning classes and objects. I would like to know how to personalize the color of the title bar in the most simple way as I am a beginner. If you want me to send you the code that is in the header file (.h file) I can.

Comment: Practically speaking, you don't.  The system title bar styles and colors are a combination of user preferences and OS styles.  Some apps will hide the default title bar and draw their own, but that's an advanced thing.

Comment: You could look into overriding your Form's `WndProc` method and handle the `WM_NCPAINT` message.

Comment: I thank you a lot @selbie for clearing up this, because I was really confused.